# Bluff ratio step solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a mathematics book for poker and came across this equation:

$P$ = pot bets
$c$ = frequency player x calls
bluff bet = 1

(pot size)(frequency x folds) = (bluff bet)(frequency x calls)
$P(1-c) = c$
???
$c = P/(P+1)$

I need help to understand the steps between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(1-c)=c$

$P -Pc=c$

$P = c+Pc$

$P= c(P+1)$

$c = P/(P+1)$

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, thank you! But I still have a problem understanding $c + Pc$ to $c(P+1)$. I'm so new to this. :D

Comment: It's factorization. Try multiplying out c(P+1) and see that you get the same.

Comment: Indeed. I guess I'll head back to algebra fundamentals.